# Bulk User Creation in Rails - good use of delayed_job?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, administration, delayed-job

In the administration panel for my rails application I want to give the administrator the ability to create several users at one time (in the hundreds range). Would this be a good use for delayed_job?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.

Here the criteria I use to determine if a delayed job should be used or not:

1. Can this be a time intensive task?
2. Is it a time sensitive task?
3. Is it going to block the user from using the application until it finishes?
4. Can it be automated easily?

If my answers were Yes, No, No, Yes, then I would use a delayed job. Your situation meets my criteria.

Comment: Really like this criteria set for using delayed job.

Answer (score 2):

I guess the users don't need to be created right away. If they are within the next 5 minutes, it's ok.
Then yeah, this is applicable with delayed job.